# Inflate layout referenced by parent layout using 'include' tag

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a main activity layout, which has a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, inside which I have a custom layout/view. I added this custom layout to the `CollapsingToolbar` using the 'include' tag, and it displays fine, but I'm failing inflating the custom layout from the activity. This:

```
  RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.create_quote_toolbar_layout);
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_quote_toolbar, r, false);
  TextView T = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lineTotal);
  T.setText("sdrsfLineTotal");
```

does not seem to work.

**main_activity_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".CreateQuoteActivity" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="100dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp" >

            <include layout="@layout/create_quote_toolbar"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:clipToPadding="false" >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/list"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**custom_toolbar_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/create_quote_toolbar_layout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/deliverToAddress"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deliverToAddress"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Valid Until:"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expirationDate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:hint="dd/mm/yyyy"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expirationDate"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Item Description"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:hint="Quantity"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/unitPrice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:hint="Unit Price"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/discount"
        android:layout_below="@+id/unitPrice"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/unitPrice"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/unitPrice"
        android:hint="Discount"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/lineTotal"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/discount"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/discount"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/discount"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Item"
        android:id="@+id/addItemButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/expirationDate"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/expirationDate"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send Quote"
        android:id="@+id/respondButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/total"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/total"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you want to inflate it? What is your goal?

Comment: Iv got buttons and other widgets i need to set listeners on etc...basically make it functional

Comment: You're inflating, but are you adding that inflated view to your activity's view as a subview as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set the root view in the activity with setContentView there is no reason for you to inflate the view. When you use the  tag in the xml it will automatically inflate the view when you set it in the Activity.

If you want to find a view you would then simply do a `findViewById` on the id as normally for the other ids.

For example, you would in your onCreate method do:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout)
```

After this you can simply do

```
findViewById(create_quote_toolbar_layout)
```

And that will find the RelativeLayout in the view you included.

Comment: "If you have set the root view in the activity with setContentView there is no reason for you to inflate the view. When you use the tag in the xml it will automatically inflate the view when you set it in the Activity....". So simple..that did the trick.